# ¿Cómo solucionar error: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column?

Tags: sql-server

Ahora que ejecute el trigger no me permite hacer insert me sale lo siguiente:

> Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TR_TB_DISTRITO_INS, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 28] Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'TB_DISTRITO_AUDITORIA' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Esta es mi ***TB_AUDITORIA*** para la table distrito:

```
Create table [TB_DISTRITO_AUDITORIA] 
(
    [COD_DIS] Integer Identity(101,1) NOT NULL, 
    [NOM_DIS] Varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    [FECHA_ACCION] DateTime,
    [ACCION] varchar(20)
) 
alter table [TB_DISTRITO_AUDITORIA]
alter column [COD_DIS] INTEGER NOT null
go
```

Este es mi ***trigger*** de auditoria para insert:

```
create trigger [TR_TB_DISTRITO_INS]
on [TB_DISTRITO]
for insert
as
insert into [TB_DISTRITO_AUDITORIA]
(COD_DIS,NOM_DIS,FECHA_ACCION,ACCION)
select COD_DIS,NOM_DIS,GETDATE(),'INSERTADO'
from inserted
go
```

Y esta es mi ***TB_DISTRITO***

```
Create table [TB_DISTRITO] (
    [COD_DIS] Integer Identity(101,1) NOT NULL,
    [NOM_DIS] Varchar(30) NOT NULL,
Primary Key  ([COD_DIS])
) 
go
```

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Lo que te esta diciendo el error, es que estás intentando insertar un valor en una columna que es `IDENTITY` cosa que por definición no se puede. ¿Realmente quieres insertar un valor explicito? Sino, simplemente quita la columna del insert y deja que el motor la complete: `insert into [TB_DISTRITO_AUDITORIA] (NOM_DIS,FECHA_ACCION,ACCION)`

Answer (score 3):

El error `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table` básicamente te está diciendo que no puedes insertar un valor explícito en una columna que sea del tipo `IDENTITY`, lo cual es razonable ya que este tipo de datos es un autonumérico que lo maneja directamente el motor de la base de datos.

Deberías quitar de la clausula de `INSERT` la columna `COD_DIS`, el valor de la misma lo administra la BD:

```
insert into [TB_DISTRITO_AUDITORIA] (NOM_DIS,FECHA_ACCION,ACCION)
select NOM_DIS,GETDATE(),'INSERTADO'
       from inserted;
```

Pero, si efectivamente el valor que debes insertar es el que se obtiene de la inserción en `TB_DISTRITO`, que entiendo es lo más probable dado que se trata de una tabla de auditoría, el problema, es otro: La definición de la tabla `TB_DISTRITO_AUDITORIA` es incorrecta, `COD_DIS` no debiera ser un `IDENTITY`:

```
Create table [TB_DISTRITO_AUDITORIA] 
(
    [COD_DIS] IntegerNOT NULL, 
    [NOM_DIS] Varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    [FECHA_ACCION] DateTime,
    [ACCION] varchar(20)
)
```